# How are left join, inner join, union of mysql can be replicated in redis

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, cross-reference, node-redis

I think cross referancing is a good way of learning. I made some research on redis and it seams that as a schameless database redis don't have tables. Instead of tables it has got key-value, key-list, key-set and key-sortedset(zset) pairs.

This kind of key-data pair structure is too unfamiliar for me. I'm more used to mysql, sql styled databases.

I got a sqlFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/125ab/3) it demonostrates a simple inner join example.

I offenly take this data from sql and re-model it to a meaningfull JSON object like this:

```
var posts = {
    users: [{
        userid: 1,
        posts: [{
            header: "header1",
            content: "content of header1"
        },{
            header: "header2",
            content: "content of header2"
        },{
            header: "header3",
            content: "content of header3"
        }]
    },{
        userid: 2,
        posts: [{
            header: "header4",
            content: "content of header4"
        }]
    }]
}
```

My question is:

How can I mimic this kind of table structure on redis and node.js?
Is there a build in redis command for foraign keys?
If I have no option but using app level data re-modeling how is the proper way to doing that kind of process.

PS: Cross referancing examples and usefull articals would be apriciated.

**EDIT:**
Is join like operations can be done by SINTER command of Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a key-value store and not a relational database.  As such, there is no native function that would maintain entity relationships.  If you wanted it, you'd have to write this into your app.

The closest thing I can think of is what you find in the [Mongoose.js](http://mongoosejs.com/) module.  Mongoose defines a [Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) that defines fields used to format and validate documents fetched/saved with MongoDB and also allows for [subdocs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) which could *possibly* start to mimic relationships between entities.

...but considering that Redis has a record expiration/TTL feature built-in, that records are stored in RAM, that it's a key-value store....it feels a misplaced effort to attempt this.  Even Mongoose doesn't provide functionality to enforce referential integrity between collections and limits help to improving record consistency with validation/typing via its Schema.

Comment: WOW. Look at that young dev who is at the start of his career. He had dreams and lots of questions about the new world that he just entered. The world of development. And thanks to you for the help that you provided to him. Here, after 7 years I guess you earn your "Accepted Answer" points.